# How can I understand <package>Config.cmake, <package>ConfigVersion.cmake, <package>Targets.cmake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to understand what I do with my cmake files. I'm sorry if my question seems too obvious or already reply in an other place but I have a real difficulty to understand modern cmake and find good and clear explanations.
I have write a minimal example :

hello.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>

int hello(){
   std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project (hello)

SET(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "/home/guillaume/dev/C++/projects/test/cmake_hello_world/install")
set(INSTALL_LIB_DIR lib)

add_library(hello SHARED main.cpp)

set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib)
set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR include)

INSTALL(TARGETS hello
  EXPORT helloTargets
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR}
  INCLUDES DESTINATION ${INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR})

include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
set(ConfigFileInstallDir lib/cmake/hello)
set(INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR include CACHE PATH "install path for include files")
set(LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR lib CACHE PATH "install path for libraries")
configure_package_config_file(helloConfig.cmake.in
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloConfig.cmake"
  INSTALL_DESTINATION "${ConfigFileInstallDir}"
  PATH_VARS INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR
  )
write_basic_package_version_file(
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloConfigVersion.cmake"
  VERSION "0.0.0"
  COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)

EXPORT(EXPORT helloTargets
  FILE helloTargets.cmake)

INSTALL(FILES
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloConfig.cmake"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloConfigVersion.cmake"
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/helloTargets.cmake"
  DESTINATION "${ConfigFileInstallDir}")
```

and helloConfig.cmake.in :

```
set(helloLib_VERSION @VERSION@)

@PACKAGE_INIT@

INCLUDE("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/helloTargets.cmake")

SET_AND_CHECK(hello_LIB_DIR "@PACKAGE_LIBRARY_INSTALL_DIR@")

message(STATUS "hello library version: ${hello_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "hello library location: ${hello_LIB_DIR}")

check_required_components(hello)
```

Now, I have three files in cmake_hello_world/install/lib/cmake/hello

- From configure_package_config_file, helloConfig.cmake
- From write_basic_package_version_file, helloConfigVersion.cmake
- From EXPORT(export ...), helloTargets.cmake

Ok, I believe I know that helloConfig.cmake will be used by future findpackage(hello), but what is the meaning of the two others files (helloConfigVersion.cmake and helloTargets.cmake)? When should I create them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what is the meaning of the two others files (helloConfigVersion.cmake

`helloConfigVersion` is used for detecting or choosing the version of the package, without including it. Basically it works like this, in psuedocode:

```
function(find_package VERSION some_version)
     # blabla
     # variable set by find_package before including
     set(PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION ${some_version})
     include(helloConfigVersion) # uses PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION
     # if PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION is compatible with the version installed
     # then the variable PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE is set inside helloConfigVersion
     # (this would all be easier if cmake wouldn't use so many global variables...)
     if (NOT PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE)
         message(FATAL_ERROR "Och no, the installed package version is not compatible with what you want!")
     endif()
     # all ok, the version is compatible, we can do it
     include(helloConfig.cmake)
     # blabla
endfunction()
```

See the relevant section in `find_package` manual, all described there.

> and helloTargets.cmake)?

This file defines (or switches between versions of) targets of your library. It basically does in pseudocode:

```
add_library(hello SHARED IMPORTED /usr/lib/the/path/to/libhello.so)
```

along with some other stuff. `find_package` sources that file, so you can later use `target_link_libraries(soemtarget hello)` like it would-have-been compiled as a cmake target.

In some cases the `*Target.cmake` file is missing, I think that is when the library exports no targets and does only functions or does a lot of manual stuff.

> When should I create them ?

If you want your module to be found with `find_package`, then always. You could not create the `Version.cmake` file, then if the user does `find_package(hello VERSION <any verison here>)` it will always *error*.

> How can I understand Config.cmake, ConfigVersion.cmake, Targets.cmake

They are just a part of cmake packaging system.